# jquery mousein mouseout remove add class to specific link in span

Tags: jquery, class

Alright what i'm trying to do is remove a class when i mouse in on a link. But the class to be removed is on a different link. And then when i mouse out the class will be returned to the link it was removed from.  Any advise?

```
google.load("jquery", "1.3.1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
{
  $(".nav a").hover(function(ev) {
    $(".nav a").each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    },function(ev) {
      $(".nav a").each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: you need to share the target markup... look at [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: "Any advise?" ya post relevant code you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this. Try this [JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UsItUxU/3/edit?css,js,output)

```
var $items = $(".nav a");

$items.mouseover(function(ev) {
  $items.removeClass('active');
  $(ev.currentTarget).addClass('active');
}

$items.mouseout(function(ev) {
  $(ev.currentTarget).removeClass('active');
}
```